# Insert a list into an epigraph environment

Tags: lists, epigraphs

I would like to produce the following with a list:

```
\epigraph{There are only four systems that bridge all linguistic barriers:\\

--The complete set of mathematical symbols,\\

--The International System of Units,\\

--The symbols for chemical elements,\\

--The way of writing notes for music.
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works if you add `\leavevmode` after the end of an `\itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{There are only four systems that bridge all linguistic barriers:
%
\begin{itemize}
\item The complete set of mathematical symbols,
\item The International System of Units,
\item The symbols for chemical elements,
\item The way of writing notes for music.
\end{itemize}
%
\leavevmode}{}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]